# Using VLOOKUP with an IF statement to search a range and return description

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup

I have a sheet (Sheet 1) with the name of an event and another sheet (Sheet 2) with the name of the same events along with event descriptions. Not all events from Sheet 2 are in Sheet 1.

I am attempting to obtain a description of the event for Sheet 1 if it is in Sheet 2. Essentially, I want my formula to say is: if 'Sheet1 a2' is in 'Sheet2 a2:a200' return corresponding description from 'Sheet 2 column b'.

Added an example of my data below, hopefully it will clarify my question.

**Sheet 1:**

```
Group   Type    Desc
boots   name1   
        name5   
        name3

sandals name8    
        name2    
        name11
```

**Sheet 2:**

```
Type    Desc
name1   12 in boot, brown
name2   flip flop sandal, white
name3   steel toe, black
name4   hi top, black basketball shoe
name5   logger, brown, steel toe
name6   slip ons
```

Comment: If Sheet1!A2 is in Sheet2!A:A then a [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) will return the value from column B with `=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A2, Sheet2!A:B, 2, FALSE)`. If Sheet1!A2 is NOT in Sheet2!A:A then the same formula will return `#N/A`. What is the question?

Comment: Are the values in Sheet1 a superset of the values in Sheet2?

Comment: Here's an example of my data. Hope this clarifies my question

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is the "N/A" error showing up when it's not found, you can use this formula to just display blank instead:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(D1,A:B,2,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP(D1,A:B,2,FALSE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can also use

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D1,A:B,2,FALSE),"")
```

to avoid displaying any error